# Función en Javascript arroja NaN al intentar calcular las cuotas en este simulador de préstamos

Tags: javascript, funciones, function, parsear, numberformat

En este código, se intenta realizar un simulador de préstamos. El algoritmo anda bien desde el principio, pero el resultado que arroja es NaN cuando se intenta calcular el precio de las cuotas dentro del simulador. Intenté parsear los datos ingresados por prompt e incluso utilizar el método Number en los console.log pero sigue dando NaN al intentar imprimir ambos resultados en la consola... ¿algún error por simple que sea y no logre ver?

```
function cantidad1(){
    let cantidad1 = parseInt(prompt("ingresar cantidad a prestar"));
    alert("La cantidad es = " + cantidad1)
}
function cuotas1(){
    let cuotas1 = parseInt(prompt("En cuantas cuotas quiere pagar, elija de 1 a 12"));
    alert("Desea el prestamo en " + cuotas1 + " cuotas?")
}
let cantidad = console.log(Number(cantidad1()))
let cuotas = console.log(Number(cuotas1()))

function dividir(dato1, dato2){
    resultado = dato1 / dato2;
}
dividir(cantidad, cuotas)
alert(resultado)
```

Comment: 1. Variables cantidad y cuotas estan mal definidas 2. Variable resultado le falta el let 3. Tus funciones les hace falta un return, para que retornen un valor y poderlo capturar en una variable

Comment: Recuerda votar positiva una respuesta si te fue util o seleccionar alguna como correcta si solucionaron tu problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola bro tienes un poco de desorden en tu codigo, te recomiendo poner comentarios para identificar que hace tu algoritmo, te falta decirle a las funciones que retornen un valor.
No puedes definir una variable como let var = console.log, eso esta mal.. Y por ultimo olvidaste definir resultado como variable. Aqui te dejo el codigo funcionando:

```js
            //Funcion para ingresar cantidad a prestar
            function cantidad1(){
                let cantidad1 = parseInt(prompt("ingresar cantidad a prestar"));
                alert("La cantidad es = " + cantidad1)
                return cantidad1
            }

            //Funcion para ingresar cuotas a pagar
            function cuotas1(){
                let cuotas1 = parseInt(prompt("En cuantas cuotas quiere pagar, elija de 1 a 12"));
                alert("Desea el prestamo en " + cuotas1 + " cuotas?")
                return cuotas1
            }

            //Capturar resultado de funciones
            let cantidad = cantidad1()
            let cuotas = cuotas1()

            //Mostrar resultado de funciones
            console.log("La cantidad es: " + cantidad)
            console.log("Las cuotas son:" + cuotas)

            //Funcion para dividir cantidad en cuotas
            function dividir(dato1, dato2){
               let resultado = dato1 / dato2;
               return resultado
            }

            //Capturar cantiddad / cuotas
            let division = dividir(cantidad, cuotas)

            //Mostrar resultado
            console.log("Usted debe pagar " + cuotas + " cuotas de " + division)
```